# Show image from HTML tag in text view?

Tags: android, html, image

Xml Layout

```
<org.sufficientlysecure.htmltextview.HtmlTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Java

```
txtDescription.setHtml(object.getString("content"), new HtmlHttpImageGetter(txtDescription));
```

Response from server

```
{"success":"true","Content":{"id":115,"title":"vvipprogram","content":"<img src=\"https://example.com//media//images//topvvip.jpg" alt=\"topvvip\" width=\"43%\"\/>\r\n"}}
```

Result Screenshot

[image]

I Want to show this image in full page ? How to do this ? plz help me .

Comment: you are setting the image in txtDescription right ?

Comment: You already tried to replace android: layout_width = "wrap_content" with android: layout_width = "match_parent"

Comment: already tried this but not working @Vladimir Salguero

Comment: xml is shown on above of question @Code-Read

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this code for set html image and text both from textview:

This is xml code:

```
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

This is Java code:

```
public class ConditionOfUseActivity extends Activity implements Html.ImageGetter {
     private TextView txtDescription;
     private Drawable empty;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_condition_use);
        txtDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        String source = "this is a test of <b>ImageGetter</b> it contains " +
            "two images: <br/>" +
            "<img src=\"http://developer.android.com/assets/images/dac_logo.png\"><br/>and<br/>" +
            "<img src=\"http://developer.android.com/assets/images/icon_search.png\">";           
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(object.getString("content"), ConditionOfUseActivity.this, null);
        txtDescription.setText(spanned); 
     }

     @Override
     public Drawable getDrawable(String s) {
       LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
       empty = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash1);
       d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
       d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());
       new LoadImage().execute(s, d);
       return d;
    }

    class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {
       private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

       @Override
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
          String source = (String) params[0];
          mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
          Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground " + source);
          try {
            InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
            //mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());
            mDrawable.setLevel(1);
            CharSequence t = txtDescription.getText();
            txtDescription.setText(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me that spalsh1 is any png or jpg file? As I have taken a png file in-place of splash1 but that same image is loading instead of loading the network image. Please do let me know what is splash1 here if it is empty drawable how did you create it?